# Leibniz formula for Pi - Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble writing a function to compute an approximation for pi using the leibniz notation.

Leibniz Formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80#Inefficiency

If someone could help point me in the right direction for doing this, it would be great

thanks

Comment: @A.R.S. That comment is too old ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien It may be, but it's an important one.

Comment: @A.R.S. haha agreed but just try to make a new version of it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well here's my idea, using `sum` and a generator expression:

```
n = 5000000  # terms of sequence to include

print 4 * sum((-1.)**k / (2*k + 1) for k in xrange(n))
print math.pi  # for comparison
```

```
3.14159245359
3.14159265359
```

Using the identity you posted:

[image]

If you didn't read it already, this sum converges rather slowly so it isn't a particularly good way to approximate pi.

Comment: It would be quicker to sum the odd numbers and even numbers sepratly and not to use `**k`: `print 4 * (sum((1.) / (2*k + 1) for k in xrange(0,n,2)) + sum((-1.) / (2*k + 1) for k in xrange(1,n,2)))`

Comment: unless python has optimization for `-1` powers.. we have to timeit